# Collection of beginner tips thread?

Tags: discussion

I stumbled on [Creating a realistic world Series](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2594/creating-a-realistic-world-series) today.

I think this will be a great help to users, especially new ones, to improve their map making skill when creating a world.

---

Is there any post like "collection of tips" so we can direct new users to improve their posts?

Comment: Other things you should stumble on: https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4019 and 9my own series!) https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4877/lessons-in-writing-questions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is indeed such a post. We had issues with new users having trouble with their questions a while ago, so we as a community had a [discussion](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3567/6986) and, from that, devised a set of [parameters](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3624/6986) that questions should meet to be acceptable by the community.

Comment: There are lots of bits of useful information about asking and answering questions, about criteria for voting to open or close questions, and almost without fail it is bollixing hard to find. It would be brilliant to find it all in one easily accessible location.

Comment: Plus one for providing access to a really useful discussion. Wish they were linked to on help.

Comment: @a4android that is what I wondered at first, if there is such post it's better to leave it on a more prominent area for new users, such as Help Center, or About.

Comment: @Vylix We're wondering the same thing. It would make life here so much easier.